# Getting years from database

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, derby

I have a database field of Date type in Derby. I need to get the years in all that are in the date. The program is in java swing. I tried the following code:

```
SELECT year(DATE) FROM BILLING
```

Then i try to populate the years in a jCombobox by the following code:

```
jComboBox1.addItem(resultSet.getString("DATE"));
```

But it shows an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: There is no column named: DATE.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What is the name of the column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving an alias to your result and it should work fine :

```
SELECT year(DATE) as y FROM BILLING
```

and fetch it :

```
jComboBox1.addItem(resultSet.getString("y"));
```

or try this way:

```
jComboBox1.addItem(resultSet.getString("year(DATE)"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT year(DATE) AS DATE FROM BILLING
```

If you want to call it DATE in your code you have to alias it to the name DATE.

year(DATE) has no column name.